# How can I enlarge the window to completely see the blank field, in John's Background Switcher?

Tags: windows-10

Please see the green arrow below. I just downloaded the newest version of John's Background Switcher, but I can't see the blank field for inputting URL's. And I see no button to enlarge or maximize the window.

Is this issue with the program? Or my Windows 10 laptop?

[image: Moderator, please approve this?]

Comment: Have you checked support documents or contacted the dev?

Comment: What if you uninstall and reinstall the same app? Try changing the Windows theme if any. What if you change the screen resolution in your Windows 10? Is a previous version of the same app available for download? If so, just try that as well. What version of Windows 10 do you have? It could be that the app may not be fully compatible with latest 21H1, if so, just a guess. I tried it on my Windows 10 2004 (VM) and the dialog box for RSS Feed just displayed correctly with full text box clearly editable.